# How to style options in Appmaker MultiSelect Widget

Tags: css, google-app-maker

I'm trying to use CSS to stylize the options within the MultiSelect widget, for example to make a border around each of the individual options.

Is there any way to do this through Appmaker? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app-MultiSelect-Item is what you are looking for to customize the options.

For example:

```
.app-MultiSelect-Item {                       
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  border: 1px black solid ;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #FF9800;
}
```

Comment: The question states they tried `app-MultiSelect-Item` and that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is different for checked/unchecked options

The following example has rounded borders on the sides. Red for unselected and green for selected (with a green background)

```
.app-MultiSelect-Input { 
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: Verdana;

}
.app-MultiSelect-Item {
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-right: 2px red solid; 
   border-left: 2px red solid;
   line-height: 8px;
   margin-top: 3px;
}
 .app-MultiSelect-Item.selected {
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-right: 2px green solid;
   border-left: 2px green solid;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   line-height: 8px;
   margin-top: 3px;
}
```

source: [https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#MultiSelect][1]